# how to determine the gcd of following

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I am stuck at a task...
I want to determine $n$ of those terms:

$ 1)  gcd(n^{1000}(n^2-1))$

$ 2) gcd(n^{1000}(n^4-1)) $

$ 3) gcd(n^{1000}(n^6-1))$

$4) gcd(n^{1000}(n^{12} -1)) $

where $ n \in \mathbb{N} $

What I think the task is about,is to determine the gcd of all numbers of the form f.e $n^{1000}(n^2-1) $ and so on..
How can I do that?

appreciate any help!

Comment: The gcd takes two arguments, $\gcd(a,b)$. Do you mean $\gcd(n^{1000}, n^2-1)$ etc?

Comment: Don't you need at least two numbers to talk about gcd?

Comment: Hint: $n^k-1$ is coprime to $n$ so also to all powers of $n$, by Euclid.

Comment: @Liam yes, i know that the gcd takes two arguments....thats why i am quite confused..but the task says this ..

Comment: In the case of one argument $\,n\,$ we get $\,\gcd(n)=n.\ $ Observe that in the context of divisibility, $\,0\,$ is the largest(!) hence indeed $\,\gcd(0)=0.$

Comment: @helloworld1235, based on your reply to Liam's comment, it sounds like your real question here is What does it mean to compute the gcd of a single argument? and the reason you're asking is that some problem set has apparently asked you to do that. If so, it would help to explain the nature of the problem set (e.g., from a textbook, a classroom handout, or an exam), examine the problem there carefully and reproduce it, as best you can, *exactly* as you find it there. People do make mistakes when they write up problem sets, and it's possible that's what happened here.